# Why will the audio recording not play even if the audio on Firebase Storage is playable?

Tags: flutter, audio

This is the button for playing the audio:

```dart
Material(
  child: IconButton(
    icon: _isPlaying ? Icon(Icons.pause) : Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
    onPressed: () async {
      if (_isPlaying) {
        await audioProvider.stopAudio();
      } else {
        final downloadUrl = audioProvider.downloadUrl;
        if (downloadUrl != null) {
          await audioProvider.play(downloadUrl);
        } else {
          print('No download URL available');
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

And this is the `AudioProvider`that contains recording, stop, start, play audio, stop audio:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_player.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AudioProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  FlutterSoundRecorder _recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  FlutterSoundPlayer _player = FlutterSoundPlayer();

  // THIS WILL HOLD THE FILE DATA FOR THE RECORDED AUDIO
  File? _recordedSound;
  File? get recordedSound => _recordedSound;

  //SET THIS TO NULL TO CLEAR THE AUDIO FILE
  set recordedSound(File? data) {
    _recordedSound = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String? _downloadUrl;
  String? get downloadUrl => _downloadUrl;

  PermissionStatus? _microphonePermission;
  PermissionStatus? get microphonePermission => _microphonePermission;

  //TO START RECORDING FIRE THIS COMMAND
  Future<void> record() async {
    await _recorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'audio');
  }

  //FIRE THIS COMMAND TO STOP
  Future<void> stop() async {
    final data = await _recorder.stopRecorder();
    _recordedSound = File(data!);
    print('Recording file path: $data');

    // Close the recorder before uploading the audio
    await _recorder.closeRecorder();
    print('Recorded sound file: $_recordedSound');
    // Upload the recorded audio to Firebase Storage
    final downloadUrl = await uploadRecording();
    print('Download URL: $downloadUrl');

    // Get the temporary directory
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    // Get the path to the recorded audio file
    final recordedSoundPath = '${tempDir.path}/audio.aac';

    // Reset the recordedSound file to null after uploading
    _recordedSound = null;

    notifyListeners();
  }


  //OPENING A RECORDER BEFORE USING
  //IT WILL CHECK MICROPHONE PERMISSION FIRST
  //IF ALLOWED IT WILL PROCEED
  //IF NOT IT WILL THROW "MICROPHONE PERMISSION NOT GRANTED"
  Future<void> initRecorder() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();

    _microphonePermission = status;

    if (_microphonePermission != PermissionStatus.granted)
      throw 'Microphone permission not granted';

    await _recorder.openRecorder();

    _recorder.setSubscriptionDuration(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
  }

  //TO CLOSE THE RECORDER
  Future<void> closeRecorder() async {
    await _recorder.closeRecorder();
  }

  // TO PLAY THE RECORDED AUDIO
  Future<void> play(String downloadUrl) async {
    if (downloadUrl != null) {
      // Download the audio file from the download URL
      String? localFilePath = await _downloadFile(downloadUrl);

      if (localFilePath != null) {
        // Play the audio from the local file path
        await _player.startPlayer(
          fromURI: localFilePath,
          codec: Codec.aacADTS,
        );
      } else {
        print('Failed to download the audio file');
      }
    } else {
      print('No download URL available');
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _downloadFile(String downloadUrl) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        final file = File('${directory.path}/audio_file.mp3');

        await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

        return file.path;
      } else {
        print('Failed to download file: ${response.statusCode}');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error downloading file: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopAudio() async {
    if (_player.isPlaying) {
      await _player.stopPlayer();
    }
  }

  //START RECORDING A 5-SECOND AUDIO
  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    await initRecorder(); // Initialize the recorder
    await record(); // Start recording
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)); // Delay for 5 seconds
    await stop(); // Stop recording
  }

  Future<String> uploadRecording() async {
    if (_recordedSound != null) {
      print('Uploading file: $_recordedSound');
      final fileName = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.aac';
      final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      final storageRef = storage.ref().child('recordings').child(fileName);

      final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'audio/aac');
      final uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(_recordedSound!, metadata);

      try {
        final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
        _downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        print('Download URL: $_downloadUrl');
        return _downloadUrl!;
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error uploading file: $e');
        throw e;
      }
    }

    throw 'No recorded audio file found';
  }
}
```